# Google Cast. React-Native App. Xcode: ld: framework not found GoogleCast

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods, google-cast

I try to use `Google Cast` from [this](https://github.com/flextv/react-native-google-cast) plugin and I have next error in `Xcode` while building project

```
ld: framework not found GoogleCast
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**Podfile**

```
target 'XXXX' do
  pod 'google-cast-sdk', '~> 3'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
end
```

by the way `pod deintegrate and pod install` doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

It appears the linking for this Library is not set up properly. What I did to fix this was select the `GoogleCast.cxodeproj` in the Libraries Folder and updated the `Framework Search Paths` to be `$(PROJECT_DIR)/../../../ios/Pods/google-cast-sdk/GoogleCastSDK-2.10.4-Release`

[image: Screenshot of Framework Search paths]

There are several other attempts to solve this [here](https://github.com/react-native-google-cast/react-native-google-cast/issues/51).